# Upgrading Facebook-Graph API to latest version on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm working on updating an iOS app for a client, and trying to determine what I need to do as far as upgrading the `Facebook Graph API` from, apparently,
2.5 to 2.12.

I'm using Cocoapods, and currently have the following FB pods installed:

```
- FBSDKCoreKit (4.31.1):
- FBSDKLoginKit (4.31.1):
- FBSDKCoreKit
- FBSDKShareKit (4.31.1):
- FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.31.1)
```

I'm honestly somewhat confused as to whether or not there is anything else I need to do besides updating pods...thank you so much!

Comment: This link may helps you https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/v2/2017/06/14/transitioning-to-graphapi-v2.4/